# Is there a way to generate a matrix in R with at least some negative eigenvalues?

Tags: r, correlation, eigenvalue

I want to generate a matrix with at least some negative eigenvalues? I am attempting to use the spectral decomposition of a matrix to do so but it does not guarantee at least one negative eigenvalue

Comment: No constraints on the matrix other than that is has at least one negative eigenvalue?

Comment: I forgot to mention the matrix must be square ie nxn

Comment: That is an odd requirement, Just generate random matrices and test them?

Comment: Yeah haha, I am looking to test an algorithm on a negative semidefinite square matrix which turns it positive semidefinite but I need an effective method to generate random negative semidefinite matrices if possible. Or even a way to make one negative semidefinite out of eigenvalues.

Comment: You keep on adding constraints in the comments. Why not clearly specify them in the question itself? In any event, this seems like more of a mathematics question than a programming question. Perhaps [mathematics.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @JohnColeman on both counts: (1) comments can easily be skipped by readers or actively hidden by the Stack interface, please [edit] your question to make sure that it wholly gives the whole story, do not rely on comments. (2) This seems more "math" or perhaps "stats", not "programming", as such it likely belongs on [math.se] (or perhaps [stats.se] ... but probably math).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example that may help you construct such kind of matrix

```
library(pracma)

N <- 3
U <- randortho(N, type = "orthonormal")
A <- diag(sample(c(-runif(1),rnorm(N-1)))) # ensure at least one negative eigenvalue 
M <- U %*% A %*% t(U)
```

then

```
> M
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.36818879  0.02406988  0.1634275
[2,]  0.02406988 -0.72613068 -0.1872272
[3,]  0.16342748 -0.18722722 -0.3116400
```

---

To double check the eigenvalues

```
> eig(M)
[1] -0.1432527 -0.4484647 -0.8142421
```

and

```
> A
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.1432527  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,]  0.0000000 -0.4484647  0.0000000
[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.8142421
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you generate a random positive definite matrix and multiply it by -1 ... ?

In this example I'll create a lower-triangular matrix with positive diagonal and multiply it by its transpose (there are lots of other ways):

```
set.seed(101)
m <- matrix(0,5,5)
m[lower.tri(m,diag=TRUE)] <- rnorm(15)
diag(m) <- abs(diag(m))
m2 <- m %*% t(m)
```

(If you only want it semidefinite you just need to make sure the diagonal is non-negative ...)

Is it pos def?

```
v1 <- eigen(m2)$values
## [1] 5.976142640 1.908831945 0.904991040 0.037025982 0.002181558
all(v1>0) ## TRUE
```

Check that evals(-m2) == -evals(m2) ...

```
v2 <- eigen(-m2)$values
all(v2<0)  ## TRUE
all.equal(sort(v1),-v2)  ## TRUE
```